# How to avoid breaking encapsulation when using dependency injection

Tags: multithreading, unit-testing, dependency-injection, language-agnostic

After reading and watching some videos on dependency injection I still don't understand how to use it properly without breaking encapsulation.

Note: I read [How to use Dependency Injection without breaking encapsulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823062/how-to-use-dependency-injection-without-breaking-encapsulation) but I'm still not 100% sure.

My code is a very simple implementation of thread pool, which contains objects of class `Worker` which is a package-private class that I don't want to expose to the outside world (and it's really non of their concern).

My thread pool constructor requires a parameter `Worker[] workers` (I don't need a factory since I know in advance exactly how many workers I need).

Since my `Worker` class is package-private I thought that the right way to construct the thread factory would be to implement a static factory method in the `ThreadPool` class as follows:

```
public static ThreadPool createThreadPool(int numOfWorkers, 
                                          BlockingQueue<Runnable> jobQueue, 
                                          ThreadFactory threadFactory) {

    Worker workers[] = new Worker[numOfWorkers];
    for (int i = 0; i < workers.length; i++) {
        workers[i] = new Worker(jobQueue, threadFactory, i);
        // worker needs the factory in order to provide itself as Runnable
    }
    return new ThreadPool(workers, jobQueue);
}
```

So, is creating all these new objects in the static factory method the right way to hide the `Worker` class from other packages, or is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Injection would mean hiding the creation of the `Worker`s from the `ThreadPool`. Ideally, `Runnable`s should be passed into the `ThreadPool` constructor, and the `ThreadPool` shouldn't even know that the `Runnable`s happen to be `Worker`s.

Creation of the `Worker`s should occur in the [composition root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277771/).

Comment: I don't understand. Why would I want to expose the `Worker` class to the outside world when it's only relevant to the thread pool itself? (It's an implementation detail of the thread pool)

Comment: `Worker` is a concrete class. Following the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), nothing should depend on concrete classes (except the composition root).

Comment: Static methods, including static factory methods, will always [violate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002201/why-arent-static-methods-considered-good-oo-practice) object-oriented principles. That doesn't mean you have to doggedly follow object-oriented principles. Indeed, static factories are common; but if you're trying to loosen coupling via dependency injection, the static factory will do the opposite. It tightly couples `ThreadPool` and `Worker` together.